# Make a call from an android application built on titanium appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium

I am using titanium to develop android application. 
In my application i have to make call from the application.
I am writing Java Script to develop application.

So My question is is there any way by which i can make call from my application when i am using titanium,as we can do in native android code by calling Intent to call to specific number.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can make call like this:

```
Ti.Platform.openURL('tel://911');
```

Or For Prompt,

```
Ti.Platform.openURL('telprompt://911');
```

For more details [Titanium Platform](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.6.0/Titanium.Platform-module)

Comment: why this code its not working with me ? the part "//" is reading as a part of the number, :S but with iphone everythings gr8

Comment: Grace: Are you talking about android?

Comment: The frist link works for me :). you can try the second one.see the updated answer.

Comment: when i use 'tel:number', he opens me the contact list to save the number, but doesnt call the number, why ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this, maybe it's the way on android:

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_CALL,
    data: 'tel:12421342'
});
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

I've not tried it yet. Good luck!

(Aase